# Lxml xpath returns an empty array

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

Well guys, Im scraping : https://twitter.com/iForex_com/status/1019547735614255104

I would appreciate it if someone can help me out

```
import requests
from lxml import html

        finalurl = f"https://www.twitter.com/user/status/{id}"
        response = requests.get(finalurl,allow_redirects=True)
            tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
            print("getting photolink")
            postPhotoLink = tree.xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div/div[4]/div/div/div/a/div/div[2]/div/img/@src')
                        print(postPhotoLink)
```

Result :

getting photolink
[]

Comment: Did you get your html from the url using requests?

Comment: finalurl = f"https://www.twitter.com/user/status/{id}"
            response = requests.get(finalurl,allow_redirects=True)
            tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

Comment: Please avoid code in comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: sorry @mzjn , edited in the question... added some more code...

Comment: That content in that page is dynamically coded with javascript, which is something requests can't handle. You'll need to use Selenium or the like, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JackFleeting kind of thinking of that, but then it is working ok with beautifulsoup parsing :/ I have some more code there using BS and it works :/

Comment: Getting at least something with selenium , editing xpath and checking will let u guys know .. thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for the help. I had to use selenium for this, otherwise request wasnt working properly, still having some trouble selecting just the number 2 img in the xpath thought. im selecting manually from the array, still works...

Complete working code

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
import time

finalurl = "https://twitter.com/iForex_com/status/1019547735614255104"
browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get(finalurl)
time.sleep(1)

tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
print("getting photolink")

postPhotoLink = tree.xpath('//img[@class="css-9pa8cd"]/@src')
print(postPhotoLink[1])

browser.close()
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone !!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this XPath, it should work :

```
(//img[@class='css-9pa8cd'])[2]/@src
```

If it doesn't work, try with this XPath since the code changes once you get the html.

```
//img[@data-aria-label-part='']/@src
```

Selenium isn't required.

Comment: tried. postPhotoLink = tree.xpath('//img[@class="css-9pa8cd"])[2]/@src')  #### still nothing comes out.. its weird.. is there a place where u can test XPath online ?

Comment: im running this in a code apart, and im getting invalid expression...

Comment: there's a mystipo...  fixed like this : but still '//img[@class="css-9pa8cd"][2]/@src'

Comment: this is embarrassing, don't really know how to get just the second element, its not working, so im just getting the complete array of images with that class and selecting number 2, like this postPhotoLink = tree.xpath('//img[@class="css-9pa8cd"]/@src')
print(postPhotoLink[1])